# Using Loop to Export Figures in R

Tags: r, loops

I used R to create 3 individual scatter plots with same X variable, but different outcomes (Y1, Y2, Y3) using:

```
png(filename="Y1.png")
plot(X,Y1)
dev.off()

png(filename="Y2.png")
plot(X,Y2)
dev.off()

png(filename="Y3.png")
plot(X,Y3)
dev.off()
```

Now that my coauthor wants 15 more plots (Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5, ... Y18), I was wondering if there was a loop I could use to do the task I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If all "y" variables are strictly upper-case "Y" and numbers, then

```r
yvars <- ls(pattern="^Y\\d+")
for (yv in yvars) {
  png(filename = paste0(yv, ".png"))
  plot(X, get(yv))
  dev.off()
}
```

If they are variables in a frame, then

```r
yvars <- grep("^Y\\d+", colnames(dat), value = TRUE)
for (yv in yvars) {
  png(filename = paste0(yv, ".png")
  plot(X, dat[[yv]])
  dev.off()
}
```

You can define the `yvars` variable any way you want, manually (i.e., `c(...)`) or programmatically (as above), where the balance between the two is based on your risk (what if you "find" too many Y variables, some of which are not needed or correct).